# AWS IOT Button Wifi network name

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

Following the documentation for the AWS IOT Button, they mention finding the wifi network called "Button ConfigureMe - XXX" where XXX is a three-character string generated by the button.

However, when you use the AWS IOT app, they display the full name of the Wifi network, for example "Button ConfigureMe - ABC"

Does anyone know how to access and present the full name of the "Button ConfigureMe - XXX?" I imagine there must be some endpoint on the button or perhaps the Internet that provides that info.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you asking how to get the wireless SSID (wireless lan name)? The SSID is generated randomly by the device. You will need to scan the wireless networks on your system to see what is being transmitted. Until you connect to the button wirelessly, there is no endpoint to connect to. The button probably has a MAC id that you could use to limit the SSID's to one that is probably an Amazon button.

Comment: iOS cannot scan all of the wireless networks. The best you can do with iOS is get the name of the wireless network you are connected to.  Somehow, the AWS button app that you download from the app store provides the exact name of the SSID. There is no documentation on how to get that information from Amazon. The documentation tells you to look for an SSID that is "Button ConfigureMe - XXX"

Comment: Of course iOS can scan the 802.11 networks. Put your button in setup mode, then go to Settings -> Wi-Fi. You will see the button's SSID. I am not an iOS developer so I cannot help write code to do this, but on Windows this task is fairly easy.

Comment: iOS prevents apps (besides settings) from scanning all of the wifi networks. Also, even if I could scan all of the wifi networks it would not solve the problem in my post.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate you taking the time to try and help.

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this problem?

Comment: Yes. When we scan the button we got the code. Then we used a sha256() encoding to get a hex string. The last 3 characters of that hex string is what we needed.

Comment: Thank you so much!